# In pytorch, how could we save model's weight to a file in my github

Tags: python, pytorch

I am new to pytorch and google colab. Right now, I am running the python script on colab. I tried to save my trained model to a model.pth file that I just created for the model in my github. However, it reports an error
"Is a directory: 'https://github.com/***/mygithub/blob/master/model.pth'"

Comment: Could you please add more details? The question is not very clear. Which command/function throws this error message? What precisely do you mean by "created [...] in github"?

Comment: `torch.save(model.state_dict(), args.save_dir)` and the error comes from `class _open_file(_opener):

Comment: Could you please add a short code excerpt to your question including that line + the contents of `args.save_dir`? Just edit the question. Thx